# How to create a long polling in Android by using Retrofit2 and RxJs?

Tags: android, rxjs, retrofit2

I was trying to follow this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28398332/9945307) for implementing long polling to an API.

The issue is that by trying to use `Observable.interval()` or `Observable.timer()` the call is made only once and the first call is casted only after the delay, while, i would that the first call is made immediatly and then other are dont after some seconds.

Here is my method where i subscribe to the `Observable`

```
private void getTables(int roomNumber) {
    Observable.interval(2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, Schedulers.io())
                    .flatMap((Function<Long, ObservableSource<List<Tables>>>) aLong -> RetrofitClient.getInstance().getApi()
                            .getTables(Utils.getTablesURL(ip), String.valueOf(roomNumber))
                            .doOnError(err -> Log.e("Polling", "Error retriving tables: " + err))
                            .onErrorResumeNext(throwable -> Observable.empty()))
            .take(1)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Observer<List<Tables>>() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(@io.reactivex.rxjava3.annotations.NonNull Disposable d) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(@io.reactivex.rxjava3.annotations.NonNull List<Tables> tablesList) {
                    if (tablesList != null && !tablesList.isEmpty()) {
                        adapterTables = new AdapterTables(layoutManager, tablesList);
                        adapterTables.setListener(position -> getTableInfo(position, tablesList));
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterTables);

                        recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        containerNoData.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(@io.reactivex.rxjava3.annotations.NonNull Throwable e) {
                    if (adapterTables.getItemCount() == 0) {
                        containerNoData.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {

                }
            });
}
```

That method is called after another API call is succeded.

But what's happens in the app is that i have no data until 2000ms are passed, then it seems like the observable is just destroyed and it's called only once.

I've tried to use even `.timer` instead of interval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use interval by setting both initialDelay and period values, then i had to remove `.take(1)`.

So i changed my code from:

```
Observable.interval(2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, Schedulers.io())
                .flatMap((Function<Long, ObservableSource<List<Tables>>>) aLong -> RetrofitClient.getInstance().getApi()
                        .getTables(Utils.getTablesURL(ip), String.valueOf(roomNumber))
                        .doOnError(err -> Log.e("Polling", "Error retriving tables: " + err))
                        .onErrorResumeNext(throwable -> Observable.empty()))
        .take(1)
        ...
```

To

```
Observable.interval(0, 2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, Schedulers.io())
                .flatMap((Function<Long, ObservableSource<List<Tables>>>) aLong -> RetrofitClient.getInstance().getApi()
                        .getTables(Utils.getTablesURL(ip), String.valueOf(roomNumber))
                        .doOnError(err -> Log.e("Polling", "Error retriving tables: " + err))
                        .onErrorResumeNext(throwable -> Observable.empty()))
        ...
```